# Apache map port to url

Tags: apache-2.2

Let's say the I have a web server running on port 3000, so example.com:3000 and another one on the 80, so: example.com

Is it possible to map example.com/map to example.com:3000 ?

I would like to map a directory to a different port of a different Apache installation, but I would like to hide the 3000 number.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you can use mod_proxy to match the URL and proxy the connection to port 3000
2. If you do not require complete abstraction of port 3000, you can use mod_rewrite to match the URL and rewrite it to what the apache on port 3000 would serve.

Answer (score 4):

Use an HTTP proxy that listens on port 3000. If you try to use the rewriter, it will force a client-side redirect, which will not be what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

I know you can map virtual hosts to different ports using different *sites* like examlple1.com and example2.com - that's [just in vhosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html) it's pretty easy.

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080

NameVirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80
NameVirtualHost 172.20.30.40:8080

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
ServerName www.example1.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain-80
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:8080>
ServerName www.example1.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain-8080
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:80>
ServerName www.example2.org
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain-80
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 172.20.30.40:8080>
ServerName www.example2.org
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain-8080
</VirtualHost>
```

But if you want to map a **subdirectory** to a different port I don't think you can do that without URL Rewriting on the backend so they didn't know it was happening - it wouldn't be very clean.  You could do it relatively easily if you made it a **subdomain** like map.example.com

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I think is to have two VirtualHosts.

```
Listen 80
Listen 3000

<VirtualHost a.b.c.d:80>
DocumentRoot /html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost a.b.c.d:3000>
DocumentRoot /html/map
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: But I was talking about two different Apache servers in the same computer.